# Angular2 "Output" callback

Tags: angular, promise, components, eventemitter

I have a component which has an Event Emitter as follows:

```
@Output() onLoadRequired: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

This would be used something like:

```
<my-component (onLoadRequired)="loadStuff()" />
```

Where the `loadStuff` method returns a `Promise<any>`.

I need the `my-component` to know when the `loadStuff` promise has been resolved. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `loadStuff()` return a `Promise` this should work:

```
<my-component #mycomponent (onLoadRequired)="loadStuff().then(val => mycomponent.done()" />
```

`done()` in `<my-component>` is called when the promise resolves.

(not tested)

Comment: Any alternatives? I was hoping for something with less logic in the HTML, and ideally done within the child component itself, rather then delegating it to the parent.

Comment: You can pass the `loadStuff` method to `<my-component>` and to the `loadStuff().then(...)` there. You have to take care that `this` in `loadStuff()` is reatained like `loadStuff = () => this.doSomething()` or `loadStuff = this.doSomething.bind(this)` in the parent class.

Comment: I'm wondering about the 'you can pass the loadStuff method' part. Something like: `@Input() loadMethod: Function;` ?